# Como usar cookies ou outro tipo de armazenamento local no Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Gostaria de persistir algumas informações no programa que estou fazendo em Flash.

Preciso salvar dados primitivos de controles internos de minha aplicação, e pensei em algo como um XML local ou um *cookie*.

É possível fazer algo do tipo em Flash? Como?

Comment: Por que me deram -1?

Comment: Provavelmente, porque a ignorância inicial é facilmente resolvida pelo Google. A subsequente é a interessante: *"Cookie no Flash dá pau de mefistofoles"*. Enfim, é o que me parece, nāo votei nem + nem -. Oh, yeah, se bem me lembro, o Flash trabalha com LocalStorage.

Comment: @brasofilo, com relação a sua "por que a ignorância inicial é facilmente resolvida pelo Google", não encontrei um resposta que atende-se a minha necessidade. Se você tão sabido, por que não me ajuda?

Comment: @brasofilo Acredito que mesmo perguntas desse tipo é importante para o site vamos supor que um iniciante de flash digite o titulo acima no Google que por sinal é muito coerente a duvida, ele achará fácil esta pagina, então não acho que deveríamos ter esta atitude para com quem perguntou! e voto em apagar todos esses comentários assim que possível

Comment: Uai, não te dei uma palavra-chave pra pesquisar? Eu, hein, depois fica aquela choradeira "Tem que ser obrigatorio explicar o downvote", alguem explica e ainda toma paulada... Saindo pela esquerda, fui..!

Comment: Qual delas?
"metisfofoles" e "LocalStorage".

Comment: Este tipo de pergunta, que pede como fazer algo sem mostrar tentativa própria, é um pouco polêmico (participe da **[discussão](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-no-estilo-como-fazer-x)** que já tivemos sobre o assunto). Fora isso, a pergunta estava extremamente mal-escrita, e nem forma de pergunta tinha. Creio que isso pode ter levado a pelo menos parte dos votos contrários. Editei para corrigir isso e estou votando para reabrir; agora está na mão da comunidade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O ActionScript (Flash) trabalha com uma classe chamada [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html), que não é necessariamente *LocalStorage* (que é um objeto do HTML5). Você pode utilizar tanto "cookies" locais como em um [Servidor de Media](http://www.adobe.com/br/products/adobe-media-server-professional.html) e até mesmo exibir streams como sons e vídeos.

Esta classe cria um arquivo conhecido como **Arquivo SOL** (Shared Object Local, .sol), localizado apenas na pasta *"%appData%/Macromedia/Flash Player/#SharedObjects/_pasta_com_id_/"*, contendo valores de variáveis Boolean, String, Number, int e Array.

Para utilizar este método, segue o código abaixo:

```js
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("NomeDoArquivoSol");
so.data.nome = "SeuNome";
so.data.numero = 20;

var nome:String = so.data.nome;
var numero:int = so.data.numero;

trace(so.data.nome); //SeuNome
trace(so.data.numero); //20
trace(nome); //SeuNome
trace(numero); //20
```

Logo após que este arquivo é criado ele pode ser acessado a qualquer momento, até mesmo se você fechar o swf e abri-lo novamente, os valores continuarão lá.

Cuidado ao criar este tipo de arquivo para senhas, criptografias e afins. Com a configuração errada você pode estar expondo todo o seu código.

Comment: Obrigado @biio, me ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 5):

Você precisa primeiro criar seu objeto

```
var myObj:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("cookie");
```

Depois atribuir os dados

```
myObj.data.firstName = "John";
myObj.data.lastName = "Doe";
```

E por último salvar os dados

```
myObj.flush();
```

> O método `getLocal` além de criar uma nova instância, recupera caso já exista uma

*obs: as informações da resposta derivam do artigo [Using AS3 SharedObject in Flash](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sharedobject/) que tem mais informações úteis a respeito.*